# Batch process and name/save images in a separate folder

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am running a script to create masks of 41 Controls, both Positive and Negative, for a total of 82 images. I don't know how to save the masks with names similar to the original .png files, such as "Masked Control_1 Positive", "Masked Control_1 Negative", etc to Control_41. I also don't know how to save these to a separate folder within my current folder. Thank you!

I have also included a screenshot of the current directory.

[image]

```
% GlassBrains_Controls2Mask.m
clear;

Files = dir('Control_*');
Controls_Results_Structure = struct('BW',[],'maskedRGBImage',[]);

for i = 1:length(Files)
    RGB = imread(Files(i).name);
    [Output_BW, Output_maskedRGBImage] = GlassBrainMask(RGB);
    Controls_Results_Structure(i).BW = Output_BW;
    Controls_Results_Structure(i).maskedRGBImage = Output_maskedRGBImage; 
end

save("Controls_Results_Structure")

% Save the results
mkdir "Masked Glass Brains (Controls)"
for i = 1:length(Files)
    Image_Number = i;
    save(Controls_Results_Structure(Image_Number).BW);
   
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that `save()` stores workspace variables in MAT files, which are generally meant to be opened with MATLAB only, not with image viewers and such. PNG files like those you are reading with `imread()` can be created with `imwrite()`:

```
% Save the results
outdir='./Masked Glass Brains (Controls)';
[mkdir_status,~,~]=mkdir(outdir);
assert(mkdir_status,'Error creating output folder.');
clear mkdir_status;

for i=1:length(Files)
  imwrite( Controls_Results_Structure(i).BW, ...
    sprintf('%s/Masked %s',outdir,Files(i).name) ... %alternative: [outdir  '/Masked '  Files(i).name]
    );
end
```

To customize the image file that `imwrite()` creates from the output of `GlassBrainMask()`, see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: May I suggest using `fullfile` and MATLAB `strings` to concatenate variables into a path instead of `sprintf`. For example, the call to `sprintf` could be duplicated with `fullfile(outdir,"Masked-"+Files(i).name)`. Just another option other than the low level `sprintf` function.

Comment: Sure, `fullfile` is a nice addition! As for the use of post-2016/2017 strings, I am personally not a huge fan of those features that Mathworks likes to borrow every now and then from trendier languages, but I guess they can indeed be more intuitive for many users.